# How give 2 parameter in PUT method?

Tags: python, django, request, put

I have a model of books with name and id. I want to change the name using PUT method requests, but I don't know how to handle put requests in django. I want to receive 2 parameter in PUT request: `new name` and `id`. the older name will be replaced by new name but the id won't change.
this is my incomplete function:

```
def change_book_name(request):

    put = QueryDict(request.body)
    new_name = put.get("name")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QueryDict` that wraps over the `request.body` is `request.POST` (regardless whether it is a GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, etc. request). What you here aim to do however, looks more like a PATCH request.

Anyway, you can simply obtain two parameters from the querydict, and update the item. For example with:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(['PUT'])
def change_book_name(request):
    if 'name' in request.POST and 'id' in request.POST:
        new_name = request.POST['name']
        id = request.POST['id']
        MyModel.objects.filter(pk=id).update(name=new_name)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'failure'})
```

Where you should replace *`MyModel`* and *`name`* with the correct model and field to update.

Comment: what's difference here if I get parameters from POST method and change them?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi: well you can use a POST method for that as well. But a PUT method normally means: I give you *all* the data, and the id, and you *put* a *new* object with that data there. *Patch* on the other hand updates an *existing* record.

Comment: In restful API:s POST is for creating objects, PUT for updating them and PATCH for partially updating objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.http import QueryDict
    if request.method == "PUT":
            put = QueryDict(request.body)
            key = put.get("key")
```

Comment: In your code I can just get the key I want but I have to change it by hand, here what is difference between POST and PUT methods?